# How to deploy ssis package on SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, ssis-2008

When I deploy package on SQL Server 2012, I get this error.

> ResultsLoading projectSuccessConnecting to destination serverSuccessThe package failed to load due to error 0xC0011008 "Error loading from XML. No further detailed error information can be specified for this problem because no Events object was passed where detailed error information can be stored.". This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML fails.
>   Changing protection level Failure Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsRuntimeException: The package failed to load due to error 0xC0011008 "Error loading from XML. No further detailed error information can be specified for this problem because no Events object was passed where detailed error information can be stored.". This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML fails.
>
> ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The package failed to load due to error 0xC0011008 "Error loading from XML. No further detailed error information can be specified for this problem because no Events object was passed where detailed error information can be stored.". This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML fails.
>
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.IDTSPackagePersist100.LoadPackageFromXML(Object vSource, Boolean vbSourceIsLocation, IDTSEvents100 pEvents)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Package.LoadFromXML(String packageXml, IDTSEvents events)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Package.LoadFromXML(String packageXml, IDTSEvents events)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Project.LoadPackage(IProjectStorage storage, Package package, String streamName, IDTSEvents events)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.PackageItem.Load(IDTSEvents events)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.PackageItem.get_Package()
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Wizard.Common.Model.DeploymentModel.ConvertProtectionLevel(Project project)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Wizard.Common.Model.DeploymentModel.DeployProject()Use the following arguments to perform this deployment from the command line:Command lineNone/Silent /ModelType:Project /SourcePath:"D:\Projects\vz-internal-etl\trunk\SourceViz\vizExplorerBI\vizExplorerBI\bin\Development\vizExplorerBI.ispac" /DestinationServer:"KAILESH-PC8" /DestinationPath:"/SSISDB/Viz/vizExplorerBI"SourcePathNoneD:\Projects\vz-internal-etl\trunk\SourceViz\vizExplorerBI\vizExplorerBI\bin\Development\vizExplorerBI.ispacDestinationServer nameNoneKAILESH-PC8PathNone/SSISDB/Viz/vizExplorerBI

[image]

Comment: How did you try to deploy the package? Did you use an ispac file? Or did you deploy directly from within Visual Studio? And did you try to deploy the whole solution or only a single package?

Comment: Tried with both but did not got success..   but here I used ISPAC

Comment: But Combiling / Rebuilding the whole solution works? Are you using any "non-standard" SSIS components in your package (e.g. any third party component)?

Comment: there is either version mismatch or some dll missing..upgrade package to 2012

Comment: Actually I am using SSDT 2015 and want to deploy in 2012.. I may be the reason to failed deployment? When I tried with SSDT 2010 It become success.. I could not understand what is the exact issue..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have built an SSIS project using Visual Studio 2015/SQL Server Data Tools 2015 which defaults to a target of SQL Server 2016. You are then deploying to SQL Server 2012 and the error says that it (Integration Services catalog) doesn't understand the XML it has received.

## Option 1

In the Properties menu of the .dtproj (right click on vizExplorerBI within SSDT) and under the Deployment Properties, change that from a 2016 target to 2012. Rebuild and redeploy and you might get lucky. The 2016 release is the only (as of 2017) SSDT/BIDS engine capable of targeting earlier versions of the product. Everything else is only forward compatible.

## Option 2

Get the correct version of SSDT for your environment and rebuild your packages.

### How the heck would a mortal know it's 2016?

Experience + I read the error message. It references `ModelType:Project` That is a new option added to 2016 to support the incremental deployment model. Since the OP stated they are deploying to 2012, it seems rather a logical leap.